# Recommendation on improving my code? CSS Hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make every "heading" letter change color independently when hovered. I achieved it with the following code:

HTML CODE

```
<h1>T</h1><h1>e</h1><h1>s</h1><h1>t</h1>
```

CSS CODE

```
h1{ display:inline-block;
}

h1:hover { color: #FF0000 ;
}
```

FIDDLE

http://jsfiddle.net/JRfFz/

So the code works fine but it's just counter-productive and I guess not that SEO-Friendly.

I want to achieve the same result using a better and productive code, any hints?

Comment: you might do better to post this to the code review Stack Exchange (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: show this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JRfFz/1/

Comment: I ll make sure to do this from now on thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<span></span>` elements to wrap each individual letter inside of a single `<h1>` tag, and then have them change color on `hover`.  This is much more SEO friendly.

something like this:

```
h1 { 
    /* no code required, style it however you want */ 
}

h1 > span:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JRfFz/2/

Comment: So it should look as

<h1><span>A</span><span>B</span></h1> ?

Comment: @ErgoProxy I just updated my answer with code and an updated fiddle showing how to do it!

Comment: Thanks, you well deserve an "Accepted Answer".
I appreciate a lot your help!

EDIT: Have to wait 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

So using `h1` tags for all of the letters individually is not a good idea because without CSS, it will look like this on the page:

```
T
e
s
t
```

You should always have well-formed HTML before you start working with CSS; thus using `span` tags for the letters will work better because `span` tags are `inline` rather than `block` (like the `h1` tags are).

It should look like this:

HTML:

```
<h1><span>T</span><span>e</span><span>s</span><span>t</span></h1>
```

CSS:

```
h1 > span:hover {
    color: #f00;
    }
```